# sending multiPart mail through yahoo mail cause javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed;

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

It have been long since I asked for help on the forums but latly I have been Struggling with this problem for a couple of days.

read all the forums did all ppl did but no change.

here is my code

What the H I am doing wrong ?

by the way I am using javamail 5.1 and java 8 and already send text msg so no problem with properties

```
// Get system properties
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    // Setup mail server
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", mailHost);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.user", mailUserName);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.password", mailPassword);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    // Get the default Session object.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try{
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mD.mailUserName));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));

        Multipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart();
        MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        textPart.setText("This is actual message", "text/html; charset=utf-8");

        MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        multiPart.addBodyPart(textPart);
        multiPart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
        message.setContent(multiPart);

        // Send message
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect( mD.mailHost,mD.mailUserName,mD.mailPassword);

        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader( javax.mail.Session.class.getClassLoader() );
        try
        {
            message.setContent(multiPart);
            //transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            Transport.send(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        }
        catch (MessagingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
        }
        transport.close();
    }
    catch (MessagingException mex)
    {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several of these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  Start by fixing them.

But your problem is most likely due to some sort of class loader problem.  Tell us more about the environment in which your program is running.

Comment: Wow bill seems like u r a master in java mail.

Comment: Wow bill seems like u r a master in java mail. I am usint this class from a application that I created . it works fine when I am using it to send a single part therefor i am not surethat the core suffers from problem (but mybee u r right) but sending a multi part cause problems. i have been tring to run it without the classLoader loader and also with him but no change

Comment: This is a standalone application, run from the command line using the "java" command?  How have you set CLASSPATH?  You're using the JavaMail jar file unchanged in your CLASSPATH, right?

Comment: Hey bill , sorry for the lack of communication between us ,as i told u the program worked just fine till I changed it from MimeMessage to MimeMultipart , i sent mail and all was great. but yes u r right anyway

Comment: I have no idea what you changed from MimeMessage to MimeMultipart because those classes are in no way interchangable.  But if you've got it working now that's great.

Comment: Bill its not great! my problem is to run my application on multi not on MineMessage. i didnt ask for help with MIne but with Multi which is not working yet

Comment: Bill try to look in this function , u can run it from main with real values that uses yahoo mail , if u want i will ship u my full class and just tell me what is wrong with it if u can ?

Comment: Answer my questions above so I can help you.  If you think maybe there's something wrong with your program, test with the [msgshow.java sample program](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#examples).